# BPMN Combining Collaboration Diagrams or using Call Activity

Tags: enterprise-architect, bpmn

Let's say I have a collaboration diagram that models a process named *CheckMessage* which is quite complex and spans over few lanes and pools. Now I would like to model another process, e.g. *CreateMessage* which would make use of the previous process to check first if message doesn't exist already or if all its fields are valid, etc.

The thing is, that both processes make use of the same swimlanes and pools. What is the proper way to model such interactions? I was thinking to model *CheckMessage* as a sub-process of *CreateMessage*, however sub-processes can't be attached to pools or lanes - if I understand it correctly they just stay within a lane of activity which invoked them. Can a **Call Activity** encapsulate such beahviour (cross pools and lanes)? Or can I somehow reference the *CheckMessage* diagram as a whole?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of the following approaches:

1. Using Diagram Reference: This is used quite often when you want to switch easily to the more complex part. The disadvantage is that, unlike Fragments in SDs, you do not have ways to really connect flows in and out of referenced diagrams.
2. Repeating parts of the process: here you just pick those actions from the complex process which ought to interact with the other process. You can highlight that by putting a boundary around these and adding a diagram reference as described above.
3. Call Activity: This is another valid way. Here you have an activity which you instantiate as action. The advantage here is that you can add pins for input and output parameters.

I guess there is no silver bullet and you have to choose what is appropriate in each case.

**Edit** Regarding #3 it looks like that:

[image]

(this is an example and not to be used in practice)
The Action to the right is an instance of the Activity as you can see by Ctrl-L (show parent).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I am not sure if I can go for Option 1. as the referenced Digram has to provide an output (at least in a form of a message flow) and as for Option 2, I don't really need a part of a Diagram, more a whole of it. My safest bet would be the Call Activity, but it seems that by definition a call activity can introduce new pools and lanes but I am not sure it can also use pools or lanes of the parent activity. Somehow I think such behaviour would violate the best practices as all the tasks in a single pool wouldnt be connected by sequence flows.

Comment: Why should a Call Activity introduce new pools/lanes? It's an element on its own.

Comment: "The connection a global subprocesses has to its parent is considerably less close, and they can have their own pools and lanes." https://camunda.org/bpmn/reference/#activities-call-activity

Comment: "can have" not "must have".

Comment: I mean the important to me is the part "their own pools and lanes". As I stated in the question, the call activity acting as the CheckMessage process wants to use the same pools and lanes as the parent process (CreateMessage). Thats what makes me doubious as I am not sureif its legit.

Comment: A Call Activity is nothing but an instantiation of an Activity as an Action.